# Hotelling's Lemma and existence of solution to profit maximization

Tags: microeconomics

I was reading Kreps micro book and he describes Hotelling's Lemma as follows:

[image]

Directly after this, he states the following result:
[image]

I have a few questions about this:

1. Corollary 9.21 claims that differentiability + the production possibilities set $Z$ being closed is enough for the supply correspondence $Z^*(p)$ to be single valued. Are these conditions enough to guarantee that a solution even exists for the profit maximization problem and that the supply correspondence is non-empty?
2. Both corollary 9.21 (Hotelling's Lemma) and Proposition 9.22 say that, if the profit function is differentiable at some $p$, then the supply correspondence $Z^*(p)$ at $p$ is single valued. Yet Corollary 9.21 requires the assumption that the production possibilities set Z is closed, while proposition 9.22 does not. How can I reconcile these two facts?

Further, similar to Q1, theorem 9.22 makes the statement that differentiability implies that the supply correspondence is single valued. Again, how does differentiability even guarantee a solution to profit maximization and that the supply correspondence is non-empty? From what I understand, to ensure that $Z^*(p)$ is non-empty, it suffices to show that $Z$ is closed and satisfies the recession cone property.

Kreps defines the variables as follows:

$\pi (p) = sup_{z\in Z}p\cdot z$

$Z^*(p) = \{z\in Z: p\cdot z = \pi(p)\}$

$p\in R^K_{++}, Z\subseteq R^K$

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowing the difference between functions $\pi$ and $\pi^*$. the first function is involved in C9.21 while the second function is used in P.9.22.